# Can I upload a new version of my iOS app with a different certificate/profile than the previous one?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, code-signing, itunes-store

I have an app in store signed with a distribution certificate/profile. Now I want to upload a new version of the app. But, I've lost the certificates and profiles. My situation is that there is no way I can get them back. I think that the **"bundle identifier"** should be same as the previous version. So, I have an idea to upload the new version by signing it with a different certificate/profile. Will that be valid? Or I have to use the same certificate which I used in my previous version?

Its not obvious to me. You guys please give me some suggestions. Pardon me if this is a very basic thing one should be knowing already.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You'd be better off asking apple, but I think you'll be ok- the certificates and profiles expire and can be regenerated anyway, can't they, so it must work? As long as you are using the same developer account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long question, short answer: no problem.

Comment: is it? I think application loader will reject it.

Comment: Nope -- it's just the bundle identifier that can't change.

Comment: It's only required that the bundle is signed with a valid certificate. Usually (as a private dev) you renew that once a year (when your old one expires and you extend your contract). So it's really no problem. Been there, done that.