# How can I upload an App UPDATE with a difference Developer Certificate

Tags: ios, itunes, app-store-connect

I've developed and published an App on the App store successfully last month. However, since then, my Mac crashed and (stupidly!) I didn't have a backup of my Keychain Certificates. I've had to generate a new Certificate and ultimately create a new Developer Certificate in the Apple Provisioning Portal.

As a result - despite being able to sign and deploy the updated App to my iPhone and iPad, I cannot upload it to the App store because the signing is different.

Is there any way around this? Do I have to re-write the App and submit it a new with the new signing keys?

I've seen the question: 
[Can I upload a new version of my iOS app with a different certificate/profile than the previous one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831376/can-i-upload-a-new-version-of-my-ios-app-with-a-different-certificate-profile-th/12618004#12618004)

but this doesn't answer my question/problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I logged into the Apple Provisioning Portal, revoked all my certificates and deleted all my distribution an provisioning certificates. Then I deleted everything from XCode and everything from my KeyChain. I re-generated a new CSR from the KeyChain, generates a new certificate in the Provisioning Portal with this and then did the rest through xCode. It found and downloaded my development and provisioning certificates, one against my team, the other as "unknown". I clicked on TEAMS in xCode and did a refresh then returning to the profiles say everything set as valid. I signed the App with the new certificates and uploaded them. The App is not awaiting review :)

Answer (score 1):

your application bundle identifier & provisioning needs to be same which is irrespective with which distribution certificate you have compiled the build provided that you are generating build (ipa) for appstore submission from the same developer account.

Comment: I've update my bundle identifier in the plist file. This is OK and partly resolved the problem. How do I ensure the provisioning is the same? I create a new provisioning profile after the crash. Apologies if this is basic stuff; I've only been in this iOS dev game for 2 months.